# Get a correctly formatted date from mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime

I have a problem getting a datetime from mysql in a nodejs app.
The returned date isn't in the right format.

I have this row in my table :

```
id: 1
event: xxx
date: 2020-01-31 15:00:00
```

I get the row this way:

```
let sql = "SELECT * FROM events";
db.query(sql, function(error, results) {
  console.log(results);
  ...
}
```

And the returned row is :

```
RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    event: 'xxx',
    date: 2020-01-31T14:00:00.000Z
}
```

If I push this row to another table (consumed_events), the inserted date in the table is:

**2020-01-31 14:00:00**

instead of

**2020-01-31 15:00:00**

What can I do to prevent this behaviour ?
I don't know how I could get the right date from the database.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: <s>Not sure why you are expecting `15:00` when you say it retrieves and inserts `14:00`.  Maybe there is a typo in the question?</s>  Oh I see.  How did you retrieve the first record shown?

Comment: which timezone do you have?

Comment: @wallyk, Unfortunately there is no typo. The time in the db is 15:00. But when I request it, I get 2020-01-31T14:00:00.000Z. And if I insert it in the db, the inserted time is 14:00

Comment: @nbk, I'm probably in the GMT+1 zone. I live in France.

Comment: Well, at least there is good fidelity in the data insert aspect.

Comment: there you have your hour, when you retrieve it , you add the timezone in js. at least tht ios what i do, or you change your type of column to something that doesn't use tz

Comment: Thank you so much nbk. That's exactly what I was looking for. The solution was to initialize the mysql connection with **timezone:'utc'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working thanks to nbk's comment.

The solution was to add the timezone when starting the mysql connection :

```
db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:     "...",
    user:     "...",
    password: "...",
    database: "...",
    timezone: 'utc'
});
```